# How to verify SSL certificate using CDHtmlDialog?

Tags: ssl, mfc

I am working on a project that uses an MFC module with **CDHtmlDialog** dialog in order to display a log-in screen to the user. I pass an **https** url to **Navigate()**, and then handle **OnDocumentComplete()**. I want to be able to verify the SSL certificate of the server that corresponds to my https request. 
I've searched the net for how to do it with CDHtmlDialog API but couldn't find an answer. There is always the option to code it differently using openSSL or WinHTTP (which support SSL)   and not using CDHtmlDialog but I prefer to save the time of implementing the whole module from scratch.
Does any one know how to verify SSL certificate with CDHtmlDialog?